# functions and methods in python

Tags: python, function, methods

A question from a newbie (level 0.1) willing to be a python programer. And I'am sorry in advance for the dumbness of my question.

I sometime get confused between functions and methods. for instance `random.choice()`: random is a module, choice is a function. I have always thought that `len()` is a method,but it turns out it is a function of its own.

Comment: Jonathon's answer is the correct one. However, I want to provide a rule of thumb for python - if the first argument of the function is "self", it's a method.

Answer (score 1):

> `random.choice()`: random is a module, choice is a function.

Correct.

> I have always thought that len() is a method,but it turns out it is a function of its own.

`len()` is a *builtin* function.

A *method* is a function that is bound to an object (an instance of some class).

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def bar(self):
        print(self.name)

f = Foo("joe")
f.bar()
```

Here `bar` is a *method* of the `Foo` class, and we are calling it on an instance which we've assigned to the variable (name) `f`.

What makes methods cool is that when a method is called, the instance is automatically passed as the first argument (`self`), because it is bound to that instance.

Answer (score 1):

If I answer in the easiest way then, the functions belonging to any class are called  methods. So, all methods belong to functions actually. The independent functions are simply called functions. len() do not belongs to any class so, simply function and choice() belongs to random class so method.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I appreciate it.